# Delphi Android get device orientation

Tags: android, delphi, screen-orientation

I want to detect the device orientation in an app that is fixed to portrait mode. If I ask the `IFMXScreenService`, I get `soPortrait` no matter how the device is oriented.

This is logical, as the screen orientation is constantly `soPortrait`. But is there a different service that gives me the information I am after?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the orientation sensor: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.OrientationSensor_Sample

Comment: Thanks, the challenge is to calculate the orientation from the raw data that the sensors supply. As Android also must do this internally I was hoping there exists an API call or so...

Comment: On Android, what I usually do is subscribe to the TOrientationChangedMessage and track the change. So you would TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TOrientationChangedMessage, OrientationChanged); and then call IFMXScreenService.GetScreenOrientation.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: @Allan: This does not work as the screen orientation does not change. The app is fixed to portrait mode as mentioned above.

Comment: I think I will allow screen orientation changes for the app to get this information properly. It will require some UI work but this seems to be more easy than calculation of the device orientation from the orientation sensors data...